# Xamarin.UITest: Retrieving elements hidden from screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I want to write a UI test for my Xamarin.iOS app to make sure that all tableview elements/cells exist on a screen. I could use app.Query(e => e.All()), but this will only retrieve elements that are currently visible on the screen. Is there a way to retrieve all elements (including the ones hidden from the view) in order to assert that the retrieved elements are as expected, without initiating a scroll action?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about items that have their visibility set to false or items that are *not yet presented* in the viewable area of the view in question unless the user scrolls the view.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about when items are not yet presented in the viewable area of the view unless the user scrolls down to the next "batch" of elements.

Comment: Most tableviews, listviews, recyclerviews, etc.. will not create those elements until the user actually does scroll. In terms of a view that use a recycler pattern for memory and performance reason, the views that are present on screen are re-used and just the data elements within these cells, subview, etc.. are updated thus an individual cell/subview does *not* exist for every item in the data source. Testing for every item in a data source is not really the intent of a UI-based test...

Comment: Thank you for your replies. But ideally, I would still like to verify that the correct elements exist as expected when a new view is pushed on to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do it directly, but there are methods to scroll list views down to get more items, but the original ones will then be removed from the visual tree.

Table views use cell recycling, so they only creates enough cells to fill the screen. As you scroll cells that are scrolled off the top are 'recycled' and shown on the bottom with new data. This means that the cells of screen actually don't exist - so there is nothing that UI test can access.

I've done it in the past by getting the items and caching some values, scrolling, getting more items, scrolling etc, building up a list of items as I go. Then once there is no more to scroll, checking the values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

This was the way that I've been doing it so far. Just wanted to know if there was a more direct/faster way. Seems a bit inefficient for a larger list.

Comment: Updated my answer explaining why it's not possible

Comment: @JimBobBennett Thanks for your explanation. Could you please share your script/part of code responsible for scrolling through the list until there is no more items ? Thanks in advance